# Firebug console not clearing between refreshes

Tags: console, firebug

I just got the firebug update 1.4.2 but now my console log doesn't clear itself between refreshes...

Anyone have any idea if this is a feature or a bug, and how to fix it?

Comment: i think you better contact firebug support for this issue

Comment: Thanks. I submitted a bugreport at http://code.google.com/p/fbug/updates/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out something gone wrong with updating to the new firebug.
Besides rebooting my computer a few times extra, I haven't done anything to fix it. Somehow it's fixed though :)

Thanks.

Comment: "turn it off and back on again". best bugfixing technique yet devised.

Comment: lol, so true. The weird thing is that I had already done that ;p